# Is it sophistry to underline that a logical conclusion might stem from an ideology?

Tags: logic, political-philosophy, debate, politics

During an exchange on the subject human rights I underlined how the distinction between [negative and positive rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_and_positive_rights) (political and economic rights?) seemingly comes from a world view *[as inclusive rights themselves may come from another world view]*.

The reaction was this was not an argument and that I was an "utter sophist" in ignoring the "logical validity of a premise".

The logical validity of a premise would hint here at axioms which are normally [self-evident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-evidence), as in a statement being evident by itself without any demonstration being necessary.

What are your remarks and observations with respect to this? How could one proceed otherwise in terms of debate?

Comment: It seems that the distinction between "negative and positive rights" is a sort of definition. If so, is a sort of axiom but its "status" is a sort of convention: if thus, it is an assumption.

Comment: Premises can not be valid or invalid, they can only be true or false (or too vague for either), it is [arguments that are valid or invalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity). "The distinction...  comes from a world view" may be a true or false premise for an argument, I am guessing, you were trying to make. Arguably, everything come from a worldview, so it might even be trivially true. But what was the argument you were trying to make?

Comment: @Conifold I'm getting deja so let us say that the interlocutor described positive and negative rights as the most appropriate way to define political beliefs. This is something I disagree with as it masks extremism of different natures at a time when the economic downturn is riling up a lot of people. Contempt and politics make for a nasty mix.

Comment: Well, if it is as you describe you can drive a truck through your opponent's argument without exposing yourself. "Most appropriate way to define", really? Most appropriate for who? Based on what? I can not be sure without details but at some point it probably fell into a [naturalistic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fact%E2%80%93value_distinction), deriving values from facts. Generally, when you disagree with someone a better strategy is to pick apart  their assertions, defending your own counter-assertions is much harder.

Comment: *If* the distinction between negative and positive rights comes from a worldview, anything based on it can not be the "most appropriate" way to define something worldview neutral (which apparently you both take definition of political beliefs to be?). But this only works as a rebuttal if you can supply an argument for your premise, otherwise your interlocutor is free to reject it. But if you already undermined their position independently then your burden is much reduced, you are simply offering a possible *explanation* of why your interlocutor's conclusion fails.

Comment: no, no it is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it sophistry to underline that a logical conclusion might stem from an ideology?

Ideology without logic (science or reason) is sophistry.

Ideology is the advocacy of an idea or theory. The Socratic method is to define what is not known, "aporia", and to devise methods of inquiry to discover the  the truth of what is to be known, as embodied in the scientific method and deductive logic. The method of the sophist is by "arete" or brilliance of rhetoric and oratory to persuade or advocate for an idea, the truth of which may be incidental. Scientific observation or experiment may produce inexplicable results; deductive reasoning may produce paradoxes, and a broken clock is accidentally correct twice a day. However, the defense of an idea that is illogical or objectively unfounded, i.e., ideology that does nor defer to science or reason is, by default, sophistry.

Answer (score 1):

The misunderstanding is theirs.  There are definitely worldviews that rule out the meaningfulness of this distinction.  So it is indeed a premise and not a logical necessity.

The problem here is the jump from the notion that the definition of a set is valid to the notion that the set actually has contents.  This is the appeal to ignorance in a veiled form.  In this case the veil is the law of the excluded middle.  It seems that if you split the set 'A' into the things that are 'p' and the things that are 'not p', one or the other must be nonempty.  But this lacks a test of the applicability of the predicate 'p' to elements of 'A'.

If one takes a holistic enough view of rights, all rights are both negative and positive, so the distinction, although logically valid, is never applicable.  Creating a right imposes a duty to protect it and not to abridge it.  Any real duty can compel action, or can compel inaction.  So no given right is entirely negative or entirely positive in nature.

For a kind of extreme case, from the point of view of an entirely compassion-based ethics like the feminist "Ethics of Care", we are obligated to care about individuals' dignity to some minimal degree and therefore to stand up against the risk of oppression via accumulation of pervasive small acts.  Even when a duty is contingent to a very high degree, if the right is real, at some point, however unlikely one is to reach that point, I would expect some bystander to make some minimal investment to intervene to protect me.

And if you adopt the standpoint of a community-minded individual who expects a certain level of protection from their society, you can get there from a more Kantian direction: if I try to universalize withholding action to defend any given right I consider exclusively negative, I fail.  If nothing else, I always expect witnesses to the infringement of an acknowledged right to at least consider whether something they might do is a small enough imposition that it should be done, and that consideration itself is an action.  Therefore there is an obligation by the bystander to notice, and an obligation of the person infringing the right to question whether they have crossed the boundary, making this a very mildly positive right.

From that point of view, the sets of truly negative and truly positive rights are both empty, however logical the contrast that defines them might be.

Comment: Especially like what you say in the last paragraph and this is an added argument for an approach I have in mind :)